# Comparação de strings (que respesente as horas) no javascript é confiável? Como funciona?

Tags: javascript, string, datetime

É sabido que, em termos de tempo, que `07:30` é menor que `08:30` - falando em horas.

No javascript, se fizermos essa comparação, tudo sai como esperado acima

```
'07:30' < '08:00' // true

'08:30' > '09:00' // false
```

Porém no seguinte caso, o resultado não é o esperado - em termos de horas, ou comparação de horas.

```
'09:00' > '8:00' // false
```

Sabendo que, nos dois exemplos acima não tem nada a ver com a questão das horas, e sim de algum comportamente interno do javascript, como é que essa avaliação e feita?

Posso confiar nessa comparação das horas (desde que todas estão iniciadas com a string `0`)?

## Movito da questão

Preciso de fazer uma comparação pra saber se um determinado estabelecimento está fechado ou não.

Então fiz assim

```
<tr class='horario'
   data-agora='<?=date('H:i:s')?>'
   data-final="18:00:00"
   data-inicial="08:00:00"
>
</tr>

var horario = $('.horario').data();

if (horario.agora >= horario.inicial && horario.agora <= horario.final) {
    $('#status').html('Aberto');
} else {
  $('#status').html('Fechado');
}
```

Comment: Se você viu que o caso `'08:30' > '09:00'` dá *errado* acho que sua pergunta se é confiável ou não já está respondida, certo? O correto seria perguntar como fazer da forma certa. Eu transformaria em objetos `Date` para comparação.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, na verdade essa comparação que você fez daria `false` (e isso esta correto). _Oito e meia_ é menor que _Nove horas_. A questão é que, quando tira o zero da frente, aí a comparação fica comprometida. Queria entender como o JS faz essa comparação (ou seja, como o JS sabe que `a`é maior que `b`)!

Comment: Correto, eu quis dizer a segunda tentativa `'09:00' > '8:00'`, colei errado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu acho que a melhor forma é transformando a string em objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), acho mais seguro do que comparar strings ou manipula-las para tal. Uma forma bem simples é a seguinte:

```
// Verifica se hora1 é maior que hora2.
function compararHora(hora1, hora2)
{
    hora1 = hora1.split(":");
    hora2 = hora2.split(":");

    var d = new Date();
    var data1 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora1[0], hora1[1]);
    var data2 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora2[0], hora2[1]);

    return data1 > data2;
};
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8mmbzvo/)**</kbd>

Mas um sugestão é, caso você tenha outros usos relacionados à data e hora no seu sistema, use o [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: +1 Aff, tinha usado o `moments.js`, mas tirei. Achei que estava dando pau, mas era minha lógica que estava errada :(

Comment: É mesmo, eu ia comentar sobre o seu if: `horario.agora >= horario.final || horario.agora <= horario.final`. A comparação não seria com `horario.inicial`(caso haja a propriedade) e `horario.final` respectivamente?

Comment: Mas assim, se você usa o moment só pra essa operação, acho que não compensa ter a biblioteca. Ela é muito mais parruda do que isso, é meio overkill.

Comment: Eu sofri um tanto com datas até encontrar o moment.js. Não acho que seja overkill não. Ele é levinho e poupa um tanto de trabalho.

Comment: +1 pelo nick :D